# Why Kubernetes 32 instances giving connection timed out when i request parellay two machine with 8-8 threads?

Tags: kubernetes

when i request kubernetes hosted post api with one machine its return response 200 but when parallelly i am requesting two machine it returns connection timed out from in one machine response. I have tried with single docker container but that time parallelly its not giving error. So its clearly some issue related with kubernetes. And we have same setup in other machine but there we are not facing this issue And in services we are using LoadBalancer type. Can any one can help me why i am getting this issue. And when pods i am describing its similar to other system where i am not getting this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed specification of the k8s cluster that you are experiencing the issue on?

Comment: @PiotrMalec Thanks for replying. Here is the details of my cluster. kubernetesVersion: v1.18.2. We have 3 node cluster one is master and two are workers . memory:             526736892Ki, cpu: 64,OS Image:  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo). Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.5. we are created 16 pods and with jmeter we sending 4 threads parellaly from two machines.